# Db2 z/OS alternative for ROUTINE_SCHEMA or ROUTINE_SPECIFIC_NAME global variables of Db2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-zos

ROUTINE_SCHEMA or ROUTNE_SPECIFIC_NAME global variables in Db2 LUW can be used to retrieve the schema name or specific name of the currently executing routine.

Is there an alternative for one of them in Db2 z/OS (where both global variables do not seem to exist) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're out of luck regarding the specific name. You should be able to get the schema out of the CURRENT SCHEMA special register: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_specialregisterinroutine.html.

Comment: CURRENT SCHEMA did not work in my tests. It returned the default schema of the connection, but not the schema used to qualify the UDF that is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Could you query the **SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES** catalog? The **SYROUTINES** catalog has columns for **SCHEMA** and **SPECIFICNAME**: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysroutinestable.html e.g. SELECT SCHEMA, SPECIFICNAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES.

Comment: Are you asking or are you suggesting this as a solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain it better. Currently it is not very clear whether you are answering or asking a question.